# How to test thousands of MP3 files whether they're playable?

Tags: batch, automation, mp3

I just managed to recover lots of mp3 from a bad HDD.

Is there a way to test all these files if they are playable? I don't want to hit next a few thousand times.

Comment: Hitting next a few thousand times might not be enough, either.  Once when I recovered a lot of music years ago I went through each song manually and verified it was playable.  I didn't find out until later that many of the songs were messed up in the middle, like they got spliced with another song for anywhere from 30 seconds to a minute.  Fun.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are a couple of options.

[mp3check](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mp3check/) - free, source code only

[MP3 Tester](http://www.bynasoft.com/mp3test.php) - free to test, small cost to buy, Windows

Answer (score 2):

[mp3Utility](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Multimedia/Audio/Other-AUDIO-Tools/MP3Utility.shtml), [mp3val](http://mp3val.sourceforge.net/), and [foobar2000](http://www.foobar2000.org/) with the [foo_verifier](http://www.foobar2000.org/components/view/foo_verifier) plugin can all help.